# Javascript Object -Filter and get desired content

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an big array of objects like in photo, and I am only interested in objects that contains categories id that equals to specific id(in this case myId variable, I tried something like this but I cant get my desired output.

```
$(".category").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const myId = $(this).attr('id');
        for(const v of app['List']) {

        const nn = Object.keys(v).map((key) => key === 'categories');
        console.log(nn,'nnnn')
    }

})
```

[image]

I only need the contents of List object that has categories id's equal to specific or user supplied id

Comment: arrays have a `filter` method - surprisingly, you want to filter! What are the chances :p

Comment: change map() for filter(),  map returns a result for every input object - filter will only return objects that match your filter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter next time try googling "javascript filter array" ;)

Comment: `const result = app.List.filter(e => e.categories.includes(myId));` You use `filter` to find all entries in `app.List` for which the callback returns a truthy value. Since the entries have an array of categories, you use `includes(myId)` (or `indexOf(myId) != -1`) to get the flag to return for that entry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried your solution but got empty result. categories contains 'id' an 'name'

Comment: Thanks to @T.J.Crowder , finally solved, const result = app.List.filter(e => e.categories.find(cat => cat.id === 3));

Comment: @rai - Sorry, missed that `categories` was an array of objects (it is clearly shown above). Just FYI, rather than `find`, use `some` (nothing else needs to change). `find` will work, but `some` is more appropriate when you're only using the return value as a flag.